# Prove or disprove: if $f(n)<g(n)$ asymptotically then we can find $t(n)$ such that $f(n)<t(n)$ and $t(n)<g(n)$

Tags: limits, functions, asymptotics

> Prove or disprove: if $f(n)<g(n)$ asymptotically (when $n\to \infty$) then we can find $t(n)$ such that $f(n)<t(n)$ and $t(n)<g(n)$. The question in its original form uses big-O notation: if $g=\omega(f)$ then exists $t$ such that $t=\omega(f)$ and $g=\omega(t)$.
>
> $f,g,t:\mathbb N\to \mathbb N$ are increasing functions.

The definition of $g>f$ asymptotically is if $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{g}{f}=\infty$.

So we can say that $n^2>n$ because:
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n^2}{n}=\infty
$$
I don't think there can be another function between $n$ and $n^2$ for the conditions to hold but how can this be proven?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that 
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{g}{f} = \infty$$

Consider $t = \lfloor \sqrt{fg} \rfloor$

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{t}{f}\geq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{\sqrt{fg}-1}{f}=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sqrt{\frac{g}{f}}=\infty$$

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{g}{t}=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{g}{\lfloor \sqrt{fg}\rfloor}\geq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{g}{\sqrt{fg}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt{\frac{g}f}=\infty$$

Comment: why do we need $-1$ in $\sqrt{fg}-1$?

Comment: I was getting rid of the floor function, in general, $\lfloor x \rfloor \geq x -1$.  Also, since $f \rightarrow \infty$, $\frac1{f} \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Why do we need floor, could we have defined $t=\sqrt{fg}-1$?

Comment: we want the image to be natural numbers. square root doesn't promise that.

Answer (score 1):

What about $t(n)=\lfloor n^{3/2}\rfloor$?

In general, we can define $t(n)=\bigl\lfloor\sqrt{f(n)g(n)}\bigr\rfloor$. Then $f(n)<t(n)<g(n)$ asymptotically.

Comment: You're right, we can find one in this example. But how do we prove that we can always find such function?

Comment: I have added it to my answer.